# How to create grid with different column width

Tags: html, css

I want to create gallery-look-like home page with 7 columns each with different width.

This is a preview of what I'm trying to create:
[image]

Comment: Such grid like effect can be easily created using Bootstrap.

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: Bootstrap? How? I want add new pictures in col1-7 instead of rows.

Comment: i already created this grid but i dont know how to crop images like in second/third/7th column on top and 1-7 columns on bottom. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can style your body like- 
overflow:hidden

Comment: or if these images are within a div, set it's width to 100% and hide any overflow instead of changing body.

Comment: @bad_programmer please check my answer to see how column division can be done using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a newer CSS and HTML only solution like Flexbox. There should be shiv's for older browser support should you need it.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

There is also Grid, for when you want something more fixed:
[Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is USING Bootstrap-
Check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).
If you know how to use Bootstrap, you only have to manipulate the number of columns to adjust the whole screen.
Eg- columns each frame will fit in- 1,1,2,2,3,2,1 (But that will look very boring).

Another way is to take the width of the screen and divide it into 7 different columns by assigning a desired proportion (in percent) you want it to have on the screen. But you'll have to make sure they all sum up to 100%.
Eg- Percent of screen the width of each photo will occupy- 10, 8, 15, 12, 30, 15, 10

**In your css you can apply a white border to the image and set the height you want it to have accordingly.

If I got your question wrong or missed something, let me know.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own grid system of 7 columns. Divide the screen into 7 parts then the width of:
Each column : %of 1/7
Code:

```
.col1{width:14.28%;}//% of 1/7
.col2{width:..%;}//% of 2/7
.col3{width:..%;}//% of 3/7
.col4{width:..%;}//% of 4/7
.col5{width:..%;}//% of 5/7
.col6{width:..%;}//% of 6/7
.col7{width:100%;}//% of 7/7
```

In place of .. put the percentage.
This way you can create your own 7 column grid system.

You can also do this using bootstrap but it is using 12 column grid system.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,
this was create using bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12" style="color:red;height:500px">
<div class="col-md-1" style="height:100%;padding:0px;" >
 <div style="background-color:red;height:40%;margin-top:5px;;"></div>
 <div style="background-color:red;height:20%;margin-top: 5px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="height:100%;padding:0px;">
 <div style="background-color:red;height:30%;margin:5px"></div>
 <div style="background-color:red;height:20%;margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="height:100%;padding:0px;">
 <div style="background-color:red;height:10%;margin:5px"></div>
 <div style="background-color:red;height:30%;margin: 5px"></div>
 <div style="background-color:red;height:10%;margin:5px"></div>
 <div style="background-color:red;height:20%;margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:red;height:100%;margin: 5px"></div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;height:100%;margin: 5px"></div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:red;height:100%;margin: 5px"></div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:red;height:100%;margin: 5px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

check full page in snippet

Comment: Expand snippet and check result